# what is the importance of delimter in a feeds module

Tags: feeds

Guys what is the importance of the delimiter in feeds module. cause i only leave it as is. i dont change it so maybe its the one causing the instability of my import process.

By the way im trying to import large files from database which i converted in to chunks of csv files, which i have no luck in accomplishing. So can someone enlighten me the role of delimiters in csv and in feeds module

Comment: When asking a question, it is expected that you will have done your own research before asking for help. Had you looked up csv you would have known what a delimiter is. If you check the topic, this question only mentions drupal, and is not a drupal problem, and is close to being off topic for this board. We are here to help, not to provide tutorials. Please spend mre time learning and working with Drupal, and then feel free to come back if there is a problem. The difficulties you are experiencing are called a 'learning curve'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter in [csv (comma separated values)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files is a comma, usually. It may be changed. The delimiter expected by Feeds must match the delimiter used in the csv files, or feeds cannot detect where one value ends and the next begins.